# Integer Overflow in Summing Multiples of 3 and 5

Tags: python

I am sure this question has been ask a lot, but I have checked other forums and have tried addressing the issue, which doesn't seem to help. I am thinking there is an overflow problem, but I can't remember on how to fix it. I took a long break from coding (my fault there) so I am trying some problems to help get me back in the swing of things. So, just wondering as to what is going wrong. When I try `n = 1000` the answer is wrong but numbers smaller than that seem to work out right. Since large numbers won't work I think it's an integer overflow.

```
def n_number():
    n = raw_input("Enter a max number: ")
    try:
        int(n)
        return n

    except ValueError:
        print 'Value is not an integer'
        exit(1)

# 'function that will add multiples of 3 and 5 that are less than the given value, n.'
def sum_multiplies(n):
    sum = long(0)
    counter3, counter5 = int(1),int(1)

    value3 = 3*counter3
    value5 = 5*counter5

    while True:
        # 'sums of multiples of 5\'s less than n'
        if value5<int(n):
            sum+= value5
            counter5+=1
            value5 = 5*counter5

        # 'sums of multiples of 3\'s less than n'
        if value3<int(n):
            sum+= value3
            counter3+=1
            value3 = 3*counter3

        else:
            break

    print "sum: %s" %sum
    print "counter3: %s" %counter3
    print "counter5: %s" %counter5

def main():
    'max number is in n'
    n = n_number()

    sum_multiplies(n)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: You cannot overflow `int`s in Python, they are arbitrary precision (modulo the `long` implementation detail in Python 2, and the fact that some crazy builtin functions like `range` actually will throw `OverflowError`s since they only can do C `double`s).

Comment: There's no problem with overflow, use the mod (`%`) operator to determine if a given number is divisible by some other. Eg. `n%3 == 0` means `n` is divisible by 3 etc.

Comment: This can be done a lot easier:  `sum( (x for x in range(1000) if x%3==0 or x%5==0) )`

Comment: @Levon -- Yeah, I know, but then it starts to be harder for a beginner to read.

Comment: @zyeek -- Also, you may want to get the indenting of your code correct.  It's always nice to have something that we can copy/paste and play around with.

Comment: @mgilson I am not a beginner. I just forget stuff here and their. I understand what Levon is doing. Also I do indent right, but I just can never getting it to come out right on stackoverflow layout.

Comment: It should be pointed out that using `while` loops with counters where a `for` loop will suffice is considered very unpythonic. I would encourage you to start using the pattern `for i in range(n):`.

Comment: @zyeek -- As far as indenting, if you put the code in SO the way you write it anywhere else, and then highlight the whole thing and click the little icon which looks like `{}`, that will indent/format it properly.  (If it doesn't, keep working on it because in python, indentation matters).  And sorry for assuming you were new to python.  In any event, the form I posted is slightly more explicit which I think I prefer regardless of experience level.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're counting numbers which are multiples of both 3 and 5 (like 15) twice.

One way to solve it would be to add:

```
if counter3%5 == 0: continue
```

to skip the double counting.

Comment: ah ok. I get it completely now. Not sure why I didn't even bother to think of that. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You're currently doing this in `O(n)` time - you can do it in constant time!

```
' sum values from 1 to m'
def unitSum(m):
    return (m * (m + 1)) / 2

def sum_multiplies(n):
    threes = int(n / 3)
    fives = int(n / 5)
    fifteens = int(n / 15)
    threesum = unitSum(threes) * 3
    fivesum = unitSum(fives) * 5
    fifteensum = unitSum(fifteens) * 15
    return threesum + fivesum - fifteensum
```

You'll have to forgive my lack of python knowledge, I'm a java guy. There might be some casual syntax errors. But the idea here is that, for the example of `n = 40`, you're adding up `3 5 6 9 10 12 15 18 20 21 24 25 27 30 33 35 36 39 40`. This is the same as `3 6 9 12 15 18 21 24 27 30 33 36 39 UNION 5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40` Now recognizing that `3 6 9 12 ...` is the same as `3 * (1 2 3 4...)`, and the same with the fives, we can take the "unit sum" (`1 2 3 4`) up to the number of terms, which is `n / mult`, and multiply that sum by the mult, as we do with `3 * (1 2 3 4)`. The good news is the unit sum can be computed in constant time, as `n * (n + 1)` The only catch is that the ones that are a mult of 15 will be in there twice (counted in both the 5s and the 3s) so we have to subtract them out as well.

Comment: yes thank you. I just was lazy to look up the formula for finding the sum formula of a given range of values from 1 to x. Remember that from my concrete mathematics class. I am just trying to practice up on my python. Also, thank you for reminding me to alway look for a better way to get things done for optimization.                 In python, which i just recently read up on, I could do this sum([i in for i in range(1,1000) if i%3 == 0 or i%5 == 0]), but I am pretty sure this is a O(n)

Comment: it is `O(n)` - and i believe I have a small bug in that code, but the idea is there

Comment: Looks like I didn't have a bug, aside from the `/2` mistake I omitted before. Here's a sample run of it: http://ideone.com/YQ4M4

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are double counting the multiples of 15.

Answer (score 1):

It should be pretty fast, pretty readable, and run on CPython 2.x and 3.x.  I've #!'d it to pypy, but that's not out of necessity.  Note that range() is eager on 2.x, lazy on 3.x:

```
#!/usr/local/pypy-1.9/bin/pypy

divisible_by_3 = set(range(0, 1000, 3))
divisible_by_5 = set(range(0, 1000, 5))

divisible_by_either = divisible_by_3 | divisible_by_5

print(sum(divisible_by_either))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using generators expressions, here's a one-liner

```
result = sum(num for num in xrange(1000) if (num % 5 ==0) or (num % 3 == 0))
```